# Google App Enging keep constant name per instance on auto scale service

Tags: google-app-engine

I have a google app engine auto scale flexible service which can scale from 1 to x instances by CPU utilization threshold.

Every instance send metrics to global graphite server.
I would like to know if there's a way to set\get instance consistent name for every new deployed instance.

For the moment, every instance has it's own unique id which change for every deployed. I would like to set x names which always will be attached to one of the app engine service. without using another service to manage that.

Does anyone familiar with google service\API for that purpose ?

Comment: Can you give more details as to why you'd benefit from a constant list of instance names? Assigning a new name every time there is a new instance is a behavior of an underlying system that GAE Flex uses and I can take the feature request to them once I understand it in more details.

Comment: As an engineer I would like to see full metrics image per instance. Per service. I would like to see the data on graphite or any other metrics solution without take care of the instance every time. possible solution - attach prefix for every instance (as a tag) with increasing number - "instance-x"

Comment: All Flex instances should start with "aef-". Would that help?

Comment: Thanks Rodrigo de Castro . Is this in their documentation? Can I rely on that?